# Substitute for Explorer right click for desktop shortcut creation

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I'm looking for an efficient method to replace the Internet Explorer option "create shortcut" when using Chrome/Google. Explorer's right click was very handy. I don't see an equivalent in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I hope there is a better answer than this, but in case there isn't:

Assuming you are on Windows, you can go to your desktop,

```
(right click on the desktop) -> New -> Shortcut
```

and paste in a URL. This will make a shortcut to the webpage that will open in your default browser.

#### Updated Answer:

An alternative I have just found (Windows 10):

Click and drag the padlock to the left of the URL (as if you were going to drag it onto the bookmarks bar). Instead, drag it to the bottom right corner of the screen and hold it there briefly. All open windows will be minimised, and you will be able to drag the URL onto your desktop, releasing it to create a shortcut.

#### Chrome Shortcuts:

The list of shortcuts in Chrome can be found [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179). I don't think I see a better way to achieve what you want, but perhaps somebody can prove me wrong.